# QWidget masking with antialiasing

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I need to mask a QWidget with a rounded rectangle, but I haven't been able to find a way to do so with antialiasing. The issue is that `setMask` only accepts a QBitmap or QRegion, and of course no alpha channel means no antialiasing. The content of the QWidget itself needs to be clipped, so just setting the `border-radius` in the stylesheet isn't an option. I know there's no workarounds for setting a mask with `setMask` with antialiasing, but is there any other possible method that could achieve this, even if it's a hacky solution or workaround?

What I'm trying to achieve is clipped antialiased widget content (such as other widgets inside) without having to modify the content itself:

[image: Example]

Comment: Use the mask to limit where mouse events occur (i.e. every pixel that is not fully transparent) and use the stylesheet's `border-radius` (same radius as the mask) to make the corners look nice? *Sorry, it would take me too long to set up an example to see if it works out.*

Comment: @JaMiT Sorry, I should have phrased this clearer: by QWidget content I mean anything inside, which could include other widgets too. This would have antialiasing for the background, but any widgets inside would just be clipped by the aliased mask.

Comment: You seem to be confusing two things here.  While the mask can't be antialiased (a pixel either belongs to the widget or it doesn't) that doesn't prevent the contents and edges of the masked widget being rendered antialiased.

Comment: @G.M. Ah, sorry. How would you render the contents with antialiasing on those masked edges - without having to manually specify for each child widget?

Comment: Render the antialised edges 'just' inside the mask.  So the mask lies 'beyond' the required widget extents by 1 or 2 pixels only.  Not simple but...  It would be simpler if you could provide a sample image showing what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @G.M. Added an example. Sorry for using incorrect terminology before and being vague. I hope this is a bit clearer.